# why am i getting false output in string swap program

Tags: c++

`
   The asked program was to input two string and print their respective size as first line in output while the second line contains the concatenation  of two string and the third line of output contains the original string after the first character of both the string have been swapped..below is my code..everything is working except while printing the second string it is printing unnecessary characters because of which entire second string is not being printed
PS: i'm new to c++

```
int main()
{
string a,b,c;


   cin>>a>>b;
   int j=a.size();
   int k=b.size();
   char s[j],p[k];
   cout<<a.size()<<" "<<b.size()<<endl;
 c=a+b;
 cout<<c<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
{
s[i]=a[i];

}
for(int i=0;i<b.size();i++)
{
p[i]=b[i];

}
char t;
t=s[0];
s[0]=p[0];
p[0]=t;
cout<<s<<" ";
cout<<p;
return 0;
}`
```

input:
dlxecxsye
bfjoosgukxgywz

output:
9 14
dlxecxsyebfjoosgukxgywz
blxecxsye
@ dfjoosgukxgywz

desired output:
9 14
dlxecxsyebfjoosgukxgywz
blxecxsye dfjoosgukxgywz

Comment: Do note that `char s[j],p[k];` are variable length arrays and is not standard C++.

Comment: Why are you using char arrays instead of strings?

Comment: i think by that way we can interchange the very first character of both the string

Answer (score 0):

Your string p is of size k, which is size of input b (14).

In your for cycle you iterate from 0 to size of input a (9), which in your case is smaller than size of input b.

When you output content of p at the end of your code, chars at indexes from 9 to 13 are not set and you print something undesired from that place in a memory.

Comment: this helped me to print the entire p but i'm getting my output as:             "blxecxsye
@ dfjoosgukxgywz"                                                                                 while there shouldn't be "@" in between them and multiple  number of spaces

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the need for the character arrays.

```
// Swapping first characters
char temp = a[0];
b[0] = a[0];
a[0] = temp;
```

Please use the debugger and verify that your *character* arrays are terminated by a nul character.

See also: `std::string::c_str()` and `strncpy`.

Comment: Remember to check an answer if it helps resolve your issue.